# CRM Odata and Javascript

Tags: javascript, odata, dynamics-crm, crm

I am making my first CRM project - it's autoupdate field from some other entity. I read a little and gave it a try. I have:

```
var Code = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_codeid").getValue();
var oDataPath = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/xrmservices/2011/organizationdata.svc" ;

var Query = "/new_codesSet?" +
    "$select=new_city" + 
    "&$filter=new_code eq '" + Code + "'" + 
    "&$top=1";

var Record_Request = new XMLHttpRequest();
Record_Request.open("GET", oDataPath + Query, true);    
Record_Request.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
Record_Request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
Record_Request.onreadystatechange = function () 
{
    var Value = "";
    if (this.readyState == 4) 
    {
        if (this.status == 200) 
        {
            var RecordSet = JSON.parse(Record_Request.responseText).d;
            if(RecordSet.results.length > 0)
            {
                Value = RecordSet.new_city;
        }       
    }
}; 
Xrm.Page.getAttribute(address1_city).setValue(Value);
```

I get `Unknown Error`. How can I  debug it? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I have a tool for generating the JavaScript for REST queries in CRM: https://crmrestbuilder.codeplex.com/

Comment: Fiddler can be very useful when you want to examine the actual http requests and responses.

Comment: F12 - IE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg589500(v=vs.85).aspx Chrome: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools ... it also works in Firefox, probably safari etc. From here you can set break points in your JS code, assuming you can find the scripts. :) cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to debug when using IE is to set your browser to allow script debugging, Options > Advanced > un-tick 'disable script debugging'.

in your Jscript use debugger; to breakpoint your code, that'll allow you to jump into your code using visual studio for example.

btw > just check in your second go you are using a variable called `PostCodeId.Replace` and assigning it to `CodeId`, what is `PostCodeId`'s value and are you attempting to overwrite `CodeId` with it?

I've taken the liberty of writing your code as follow:

```
var CodeId = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_codeid").getValue();
debugger; //inseting a breakpoint as explained.
if (CodeId != null) {
    var serverURL = Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl();
    var oDataSelect = serverURL +
            "/xrmservices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/new_codeSet?" +
            "$select=new_city" +
            "&$filter=new_code/Id eq guid'" + CodeId[0].id + "'" +
            "&$top=1"; //make sure this is correct by testing this build url in you browser

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: oDataSelect,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            ReturnCity(data); ;

        },
        error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorObject) {
            alert("OData Execution Error Occurred");
        }
    });

    function ReturnCity(data) {
        if (data.d != null) {                 
            var value = data.d.results[0].new_city;
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("address1_city").setValue(value);
        }
    };
}
```

let me know how it goes.

Comment: oDataSelect is correct but when it comes to $.ajax error unidentified

Comment: I found this post https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmmusings/archive/2011/12/01/odata-with-json-getting-related-values-from-a-lookup-field-in-crm-2011.aspx just like yours did it step by step with the same result.

Comment: @Hristo -  sorry bout that, To do JSON jQuery call this way include the jquery library and json library as webresources to your solution\web resource. The jquery1.4.1.min.js and json2.js files are in the crm 2011 sdk (\sdk\samplecode\js\restendpoint\jqueryrestdataoperations\jqueryrestdataoperations\scripts).

Comment: That post should be very usefull doing this. put another debugger in the ReturnCity function (onsuccess:) so you can view what get's returned in data.d and what new_city looks like. The `$` character is just a shortcut for `window.jQuery`.

Comment: I have one last bug it work fine when i connect to the crm by it's domain Name but when i go by IP it goest true error: case any ideas

Comment: Glad its working, I suggest you create a new question with more detail to errors you receive when using IP. give more details to your installation and environment. Stuff like is it online\on premise, using ADFS?  Do you use load balancing etc.? Let's keep you happy using MSCRM!

Answer (score 0):

If attribute "new_codeid" is a lookup type (as I presume), `.getValue()` returns an array of objects. (This is because a few lookup fields are capable of holding more than one lookup reference.)

So, in your filter you only need the id property of the first item in the array. Modify the first line of your code to this:

```
var Code = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_codeid").getValue()[0].id;
```

(Needless to say this only works when "new_codeid" actually has a value.)